# how to pass columns as arguments to a class using apply

Tags: python, pandas

```
class Movie:

    def __init__(self, title, imdb, critic, quote):
        self.title = title
        self.imdb = imdb
        self.critic = critic
        self.quote = quote

    def mashup(self):    
        x =self.title + self.imdb + self.critic + self.quote
        return self.x

df['concat'] = df.apply(Movie,axis=1)
```

the result i expect to see is a concatenation of each column as a new column in the dataframe.

the issue is that Movie is not receiving the expected number of arguments and I am not calling the mashup method but not sure what's wrong.

```
TypeError: ("__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'imdb', 'critic', and 'quote'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, directly assigning computed series is clear and efficient. If you wish to use an explicit function for series-wise calculations, then [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) your dataframe to your function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape((5, 3)))

def summer(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[2]

df['sum_1'] = df[0] + df[1] + df[2]
df['sum_2'] = df.pipe(summer)

print(df)

    0   1   2  sum_1  sum_2
0   0   1   2      3      3
1   3   4   5     12     12
2   6   7   8     21     21
3   9  10  11     30     30
4  12  13  14     39     39
```

There's generally no need to pass individual columns to your function. What is **not** recommended is a Python-level row-wise loop via [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

```
df['sum_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] + x[1] + x[2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using class to do this ? If your data is in a pandas data frame, you can simply do:

```
df['concat'] = df['title'] + df['imdb'] + df['critic'] + df['quote']
```

Comment: Thanks I know, the concat operation could be any other operation, I’m most interested in how to use a class and data frame columns as arguments.

Comment: @evilwerdna you could use a class with a `staticmethod` or a `__call__` method, but using classes you're really not gaining anything unless you need to keep state somehow... Could you maybe provide a reason wny you want to do this and it's almost certainly not going to be what you really want to do and the implementation of such things will vary from case to case anyway...